# Trouble Installing Windows on a Asus Zenbook 14 OLED Q409ZA

Tags: windows, drivers, bios, asus-laptop

The context of the situation here is that after installing linux on my Laptop, I found that there are no drivers at the moment for the speakers. I tried for ten hours straight to find a solution but to no avail I though as a result I would just convert back to windows, but after plugging in the installation media and proceeding through the process, it says that I have no drivers available and refuse to let me advance any further. I looked to see that Asus has a support page for this problem but the drivers provided did no good and when using them it gave me a message on the windows installation screen that "No new drivers have been found" I've tried turning on and off the vmd option in the bios but that didn't help.

[The support page that I have used...](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1044458/)

**What I tried...**
-Tried to use the drivers provided in the Asus support page
-Tried to enable and disable the VMD option in the bios

**What happened**
-The driver when used resulted in the message that stated that no new drivers where found

[Here are some pictures of what Im seeing on my End!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DU8ku.jpg)

Comment: Try [these drivers](https://www.asus.com/us/laptops/for-home/zenbook/zenbook-14-oled-q409-12th-gen-intel/helpdesk_download/?model2Name=Zenbook-14-OLED-Q409-12th-Gen-Intel).

Comment: Contact ASUS Support to provide a page where you can download the USB key to rebuild the laptop with Windows.'

Comment: I have already contacted therm and they have said that they dont provide the drives other than whats already been given on the page provided.

Comment: @harrymc Which one would I use?

Comment: Your description of the steps you're following seems fine, at least at the level of detail you've provided. The photo isn't very useful. Either there's something special about this laptop, Asus doesn't provide the correct driver, or you're doing something incorrectly.

Comment: Which Windows boot media are you trying to install and where did you get it?

Comment: @harrymc I'm installing Windows via a USB, I took the iso directly from Microsofts webpage and wrote it dirctly to the USB

Comment: Windows 10 or 11?

Comment: @harrymc 11....

Comment: Asus doesn't provide the Intel RST driver in my link, so Windows is supposed to already have it included. I hope you got the ISO [from here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11). Have you changed any BIOS settings in order to install Linux?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue via the bios recovery option, it automattically had all the drivers installed with it!